# How to Enfroce Domain Licensing Limits?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, theme-development, updates, automatic-updates

I'm looking to sell premium WordPress plugins (using Easy Digital Downloads licensing manager) and I want to limit the number of domains the plugin can be activated on (to receive automatic updates). I know many plugin providers limit the number of activations to a certain number of domains but I am wondering how it is achieved and why it cannot be bypassed.

I'm aware that in the standard licensing model, I would provide the user with an license key to receive automatic updates of plugin/theme. When the WP instance requests a new version I would first verify that the license is still valid before allowing the new version to be downloaded.

My question is what stops a user from sharing the license key with others or using the same license on more than the allotted number of domains **to receive automatic updates**?

If my server is expected to verify which domain the update request is coming from, what stops the user from spoofing the domain by changing a few lines of code in WordPress? What stops a user from forging the domain in the request? For example, User A purchases Plugin P and adds a.com to whitelist of domains. User A now shares Plugin P (and license) with User B who uses the same license to get automatic updates on b.com by claiming b.com is really a.com. How can my server validate the claim?

Comment: the end user could remove the check entirely, this isn't something that has a cast iron unavoidable solution. You can try to mitigate these things but it's a cat and mouse game of escalation that can't be won. You'd need to ask Elementor why they moved away from that model. Otherwise, can you edit your question to mark in bold the specific question you're asking? You need to ask a single clearly defined question that people can write answers for, so that you can mark one of them as the factually correct answer for all people with this question. This isn't a discussion board

Comment: @TomJNowell I edited the question for clarity.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. You can only mitigate at expense to yourself.

- People determined to do this will achieve their goal regardless of how many obstacles you place in their path
- The GPL means you can't control how people use the code once you put it in their hands, and you can't prevent them modifying it
- Nothing prevents one user from doing all the hard manual work then distributing your plugin themselves with their own automatic updater that bypasses you and your protections entirely.
- Even if you achieved this, most people would never need to spoof a domain in the first place.
- A lot of plugin vendors don't do this "Domain Verification" **so the answer of how they do it is simple, they don't.**
- Most HTTP requests don't include the domain so unless you include it yourself you wouldn't know which domain you needed to verify in the first place.

The only method people have figured out to reliably avoid these things is to implement their product as a subscription service and move some functionality into the cloud, and sue copycats for trademark and brand infringement.

**Fundamentally, the value is not in the code you sell, but in the support services and continued updates that you as the seller/vendor provide.**

This is a cat and mouse game, and there is always a path to escalation. You will never defeat a determined pirate, no matter what licensing scheme you implement, no matter what code license you choose.

#### Misc

> I know many plugin providers limit the number of activations to a certain number of domains but I am wondering how it is achieved and why it cannot be bypassed.

No plugin providers have cast iron solutions. Most do not do these checks, all can be bypassed with a little effort.

> In the standard licensing model, what stops a user from using the same license on unlimited domains?

**Nothing**, the user can edit the code and delete the licensing functions if they wish, they have the right to do so according to the GPL license.

> If my server is expected to verify which domain the request is coming from, can't a user spoof the domain by changing a few lines of code in WordPress?

In practice people don't spoof domains because they don't need to, and because that's not how these systems work.

Your server can't verify the domain based on just what was sent in the request, that's not how HTTP requests work. Your server sees the IP it came from, but there is no guarantee the IP maps to the domain if you were to look it up, even if it's a legitimate request.

You can try to verify the domain, but fundamentally this gives minimal protection that is easily circumvented. The concern you have does not fit with the reality of piracy. It's much easier to change the code that checks with your server to always say "yes" without bothering to make the request, either by modifying your plugin/theme or via filters/proxies. Likewise it's easier to buy 1 licence and copy the updated code to hundreds of sites, or let a pirate do that for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm aware that WP has a GPL / open source licensing model. I'm specifically asking how to ensure that customers pay for automatic updates. In other words,, my server should have some way of validating that the license is not be shared or used on more than the allowed number of domains.

Comment: I believe you addressed this in your response: Not if your server send its verification back via webhook.. can you elaborate on this technique? Presumably, you mean something like this: 1) client domains checks if new version is available and send license key to my server 2) my server checks that the license key is still valid and if yes send a confirmation code back to clients website (to whatever domain the client is claiming to be) via webhook 3) the client then sends the confirmation code back to my server where I validate the code.

Comment: In theory, the only thing the client can do to evade this form of validation would be to write a script that forwards the confirmation code to the spoofed domain and have the spoofed domain send the code back to my server thereby tricking the server to allow the download of new version to proceed. Is this correct? Do I have the gist of it or did I miss a step?

Comment: As I mentioned, people would not go to the lengths to spoof the domain that you have envisaged, or try to do what you claimed. _The point was they don't have to._ Lots of people get "nulled" themes and plugins and either don't bother to update them, update them via 3rd parties, or just copy them from the one domain that does support it. This is not a useful use of your time

Comment: I've removed the reference to calling back with a webhook from the answer as it is providing you with false hope, and it is not the solution you were hoping for. You should abandon your efforts on that front. Note that what you seek would earn you a Nobel prize in computer science if you solved it, there are only mitigations to be had that get more and more expensive

Comment: I would love to read more about the callback method with webhook. Is there a good source I could read up on it? I thought it was a very good suggestion even if it could be defeated by some users. I actually have another idea: to verify the IP of domain since this cannot be spoofed easily. Of course, it won't work if the second domain is hosted on the same server / IP as the original domain but it will work in 95% of cases (I don't know if this will earn me the Nobel prize or not but definitely a good starting point :) )

Comment: IP verification won't work, a lot of sites will be behind private networks/clusters or proxies so the user facing domain has a different IP from the server that generates the response, e.g. any servers that implement Cloudflare. You should expect a high failure rate for that strategy. I am concerned though that your question is a little open ended and I realise that there may not be a way for your to mark an answer as the correct answer ( and not just the best ). Try asking about specific things rather than for recommendations/best practices, your Q is already 1 vote away from closure

Comment: Otherwise, the only canonical factual answer there is to your question of how do you verify that automatic updates are only provided to legitimate users from a specific domain, is that **you can't**. No cast iron solution exists or can exist.

Comment: I've shortened/summarised my answer further. I think you're working under the assumption that plugin vendors have fixes for this and if only you knew what they did you too could implement them, _.which is not true_. Some of the most popular plugin vendors protections are no more sophisticated than a license key check, and are vulnerable to the exact problem you're trying to solve. Additionally, I regret mentioning the callback concept as it gave you false hope, and is fundamentally incompatible with the way the WP Updater works. It is not the solution you are looking for, stop asking about it.